# How to add integers in a linked list with recursion?

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list

I have the basic code built without using recursion and with. The one that does not use recursion will print out 67 after adding the sum of all the integers in the linked list. With my recursion program it seems to read the second integer and stop, without even adding it to the first.

I have added a print statement as a tester so that I could see what numbers it was getting in the linked list.

```
// Linked list summ - recursive

int rllsum( struct lnodetype *t )

        int sum = 0;
        while(t != NULL)
        {
                sum = t->val + sum;
                printf("%d\n", t->val);
                t = t->ptr;
                rllsum(t);
        }

        return sum;


// Basic main program

int main()

        struct lnodetype *h, *t;
        int x, y;

        // build a list
        h = NULL;
        for ( x = 0; x < 5; ++x )
        {
                t = malloc(sizeof(struct lnodetype));
                t->val = n*(x+1)*(rand()%n+1)%19+1;
                t->ptr = h;
                h = t;
                printf("%d\n", t->val);
        }

        t = h;
        y = rllsum( t );
        printf("\n%d, %d\n", y);

        return 0;
```

I expect the output to be 67, but I can be entirely sure. It prints out 14 as of right now.

Comment: Hallo! Please copy/paste the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem — this code won't compile. You might benefit by reading the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It looks as though the function `rllsum` is trying to both iterate *and* recurse the linked list.

Comment: i agree with @WeatherVane it should be if (t!=NULL) & not while loop

Comment: ...and the recursion ignores the return value from its child.

Answer (score 0):

I find that folks new to recursion make their functions more complicated than necessary.  Consider:

```
int rllsum(struct lnodetype *t)
{
    int sum = 0;

    if (t != NULL)
    {
        sum = t->val + rllsum(t->ptr);
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Also, as shown your `main` function is broken: undefined `n` variable; missing curly braces; tries to `printf()` two numbers but only supplies one.